# Python Bokeh imports logic

Tags: python, bokeh

In Python Bokeh it is possible to import certain classes with 2 different paths, for instance:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource
```

works, as well as:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
```

What is the logic behind it? I just find it not neat/nice to be always surprised by how the import paths are (as they are always different) when using the examples from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find that `bokeh.plotting` imports `ColumnDataSource` from `bokeh.models`. The behavior is a consequence of how classes get imported into different namespaces. Your best course of action is the import from the package that ColumnDataSource is defined in, which in this case is `bokeh.models`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to avoid clashes you would do. If you are lucky there are referencing the same classes anyway, in worst case you might have some nasty problem.s

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource as pcd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource as mcd
```

In this case, they are both the same:

```
print pcd.__mro__
print mcd.__mro__
```

> 'bokeh.models.sources.ColumnDataSource'>, 'bokeh.models.sources.DataSource'>, 'bokeh.model.Model'>, 'bokeh.core.properties.HasProps'>, 'bokeh.util.callback_manager.CallbackManager'>,